# SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl and openById give errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

So I have encountered a problem in the application I am writing using google spreadsheets and app-script. I have put together a step by step guid to reproduce it.

**Summary:**
any script that uses SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl() and SpreadsheetApp.openById() works OK when called from inside the script editor but gives errors when called from inside even the same spreadsheet that has that script inside it.

**Error Messages:**

```
Error
    You do not have permission to perform that action. (line ?).
```

**Steps to reproduce it:**

1. Make a new Google Spreadsheet
2. Open its Script Editor ( **Tools** menu >> **Script Editor...** )
3. Choose Blank Project
4. Paste in this code

   ```
   function demo1() {
     return "cat";
   }

   function demo2() {
     return [["bob", "fred"], ["x", "y"]];
   }

   function demo3() {
     Logger.log("demo3-1")
     ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("[==URL==]")
     name = ss.getName()
     Logger.log("demo3-2 " + name)
     return name
   }

   function demo4() {
     Logger.log("demo4-1")
     ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[==id==]")
     name = ss.getName()
     Logger.log("demo4-2 " + name)
     return name
   }
   ```
5. Change the "[==URL==]" and "[==id==]" to refer to your own document
6. Save the script
7. From the **Run** menu choose **demo1**. This will trigger a question about privileges. Grant it the privileges it asks for. ( asks for access to your Google Drive )
8. Go back to the spreadsheet itself
9. Set the following cells to have these formulae:

   ```
   A1 : =demo1()
   C2 : =demo2()
   F1 : =demo3()
   h1 : =demo4()
   ```

**Note** that the first 2 work, so the spreadsheet is seeing the script project and able to run code from it ( so it has permission to run code from that script ) but the last two do not work and complain that it does not have permission to perform that action.

So how do I fix this? Am I doing something wrong or is there an underlying problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is due to  a change Google recently rolled out prohibiting the use of SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl() (or SpreadsheetApp.openById() in custom functions. 
You can still use this method from other contexts like a menu item, trigger, etc. Google had to roll out this change for security reasons and they won't be able to revert back to the old behavior. So the only possible fix may very well be to rewrite the function as a 'normal' GAS-function and NOT a custom function.

The issue is listed in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5174).

Answer (score 8):

I actually discovered a nice and easy fix for this yesterday. Hopefully, this workaround works out for you.

Reading through the SpreadsheetApp documentation, I found a function that opens a spreadsheet by providing the corresponding `File` object.

Here is the section: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#open(File)

The example shows that you can easily search for a file type in Google Drive (Spreadsheets in this case). However, instead of searching your entire Drive library, you could just use the ID of the file/spreadsheet by using `DriveApp.getFileById(ID)`.

Here is the documentation for that function:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String)

All you need to do is this:

1. Find the link of the spreadsheet in drive by right clicking the file and selecting "Get Link"
2. Copy the link, which should look like this `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{ID}/edit#gid=0`
3. Get that ID portion of the URL
4. Use this line `SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(ID))` to retrieve your `Spreadsheet` object

You can do other processing after that once you have the object. Let us know if this helped.

Comment: Yes it works! However, I have not make it works inside `customfunction`. Do you? For me it works fine inside script editor. But on using in sheet formula I have get `You do not have permission to call openById`.

Comment: @vatavale Sorry for the late response, I stopped working on the project in 2014. I didn't get to try that. Not sure if they are still supporting much in the App Scripts platform at this point.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.  I switched to using an installed trigger to run my script, instead of using a simple trigger.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0):

Try saving it as another version for your Web App in Google API. I did and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to appsscript.json and find the oauthScopes.
Add "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" into the oauthScopes.