# Open a new Google Spreadsheet file from Google Form using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to save all the responses of a Google Form file (with an onSumbmit(e) function, based on a trigger) to a newly created spreadsheet, based on a template.
Unfortunately my script stops working at this point:

```js
var ID = "I put here the ID of the file template";
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(ID)); <-- Here it stopped

  ss.copy(name+"_"+date);
```

I really don't know why, but the scripts seems unable to open the template file and make a copy.
I've also tried with a getFileByUrl, SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID) and SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL), but nothing change!

I receive this error: You do not have permission to call openById

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077888/spreadsheetapp-openbyurl-and-openbyid-give-errors) that maybe it's a policy change of Google but it's over 2 years ago. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Why don't you use `SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID)`? [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

Comment: If you know the file ID, then use the openById(id) method of the SpreadsheetApp class. `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)`

Comment: Already tried also that way. openByID or Url doesn't work, the script simply stop working. :(

Comment: Are you the owner of the spreadsheet file?

Comment: You need to delete the existing "On Form" submit trigger, and add a new one.  Apps Script has a long history of triggers silently failing.  And I guess no one at Google is smart enough to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've done!

My script has this at the beginning:

```js
/**
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
```

And I misunderstand its meaning! I didn't understand that this code forces the script to work only on the active form. Without this code it works perfectly! Thanks to everyone!!!