# Permission denied when trying to create a spreadsheet using Google script API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

In the corporate environment with a corporate account I have a Google Document. Think of it as a master document that is being maintained.
I want to add a script to it to create a derived spreadsheet that can be used by people who need a subset of data from the master document.
In the master document I created a script file so the script is bound to the document.
Inside the file I defined a function. Function does some search and processing in the master file without problems but once I try to create or open an existing spreadsheet to extract data from the master document to a derived document the call fails.

I tried several approaches:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl();
SpreadsheetApp.create("My test sheet");
```

and approach covered in the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077888/spreadsheetapp-openbyurl-and-openbyid-give-errors)

I also tried execution from an installed menu trigger or from debugger - same result.

In all cases I get a pop up with :
**Authorization required**
{doc name} needs your permission to access your data on Google.

with two buttons to review and cancel.
Clicking review leads to a message "An unexpected error occurred" at the top of the screen.

I tried different machines and browsers and switched V8 engine on and off.
I also made sure that the document is open to all in my org if I try to open an existing doc by URL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever authorize the script?

Comment: Are you the owner of the document? Do you have multiple Google accounts?

Comment: I in fact did not do any specific authorizations. I expected that I would be prompted and I will permit the document to access another document interactively.

Comment: After that I added authorizations:   "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/scripts.container.ui"
  ]
But it did not help.

Comment: I am the owner of the document and I have multiple google accounts. I have corporate account and couple personal ones and they all the time get in the way because Chrome assumes my personal account to be the default. I wonder whether this gets in the way somehow.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this behavior on incognito and check if it still happens? It might be related to your multiple users being logged in issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there were two things.

1. Adding scopes solved the problem.
2. I had an invalid scope that
   was already there (I do not know how it got there, probably from an
   example) that I preserved in the manifest and might have misspelled.
   That was a mistake. It caused all sorts of instability. Only when I
   tried to execute the script in FireFox instead of Chrome was I able
   to see a popup that gave me a hint that one of the scopes is invalid
   and I need to fix it.

Once I fixed it, everything started to load as expected.

Comment: Which scopes? Please add it to your answer.