# app script, after file.makeCopy create a new file, how to access this new file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get attachment from Gmail to Google Drive. After create a new file into the folder, I have encountered a problem accessing the new file that script created.

same as the makeCopy Function

> err: Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later. at myFunction(Code:21:37)

Appreciated any help and suggestions. Thank you!

```
function myFunction() {
  const files = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    const aname = "xxxx.docx"
    if (filename == aname){
      var oldid = file.getId();
      var copyfile = file.makeCopy().setName("COPYYYYY"); 
      var newid = copyfile.getId();
    }
  }
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(newid).getBody();
  Logger.log(oldid);
  Logger.log(newid);
  Logger.log(body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that when `file` of `var copyfile = file.makeCopy().setName("COPYYYYY");` is Google Document, the script works. But from your error message and `const aname = "xxxx.docx"`, I thought that you might try to have directly opened the DOCX file using `DocumentApp.openById`. If it's so, the reason of your issue is this.
- In order to open the DOCX file using `DocumentApp.openById`, in the current stage, it is required to convert the DOCX file to Google Document.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const files = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getFiles();
  var newid = "";
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    const aname = "xxxx.docx";
    if (filename == aname){
      var oldid = file.getId();
      if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD) {
        var copyfile = Drive.Files.copy({title: "COPYYYYY"}, oldid, {convert: true});
        newid = copyfile.id;
      }
    }
  }
  if (newid) {
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(newid).getBody();
    Logger.log(oldid);
    Logger.log(newid);
    Logger.log(body);
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, the DOCX file is converted by the method of "Files: copy" of Drive API.

#### Reference:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy)

Comment: I think I found the answer, google is prohibiting this function .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077888/spreadsheetapp-openbyurl-and-openbyid-give-errors

Comment: @JFtyv_85StvsDpDn Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of your situation? From this, I would like to confirm your issue.